# Source not found on array

Tags: java

This is what I am meant to do:

This class extends
JPanel, like the others. The constructor has two parameters: the controller and the number of tracks. You should not store these in member variables All of this is in the constructor:
Set the layout to null.
Store numTracks SoundNameBox instances in a member variable array, where numTracks is the number of tracks. This means you need to have a loop, and each time through the loop create one more SoundNameBox instance. The track number will range from 0 to numTracks -1. Make sure that there is a Tracks.GAP_SIZE sized gap between them. Set the size of this SoundBank so that it just contains the SoundNameBox instances.

I had to create a similar class before and it worked fine, however this one does not display the boxes it is supposed to and when I try to debug it it says that there is a source not found when I assign the array to the member variable.

Here is my code:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import controller.Controller;

public class SoundBank extends JPanel { 

    public SoundNameBox[] _track;

    public SoundBank(Controller controller, int numTracks) {
        setLayout(null);
        _track = new SoundNameBox[numTracks];
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numTracks; i++) {
            _track[i] = new SoundNameBox(controller, i);
            _track[i].setLocation(0,y);
            y = y + Tracks.GAP_SIZE;
        }
        this.setSize(Tracks.GAP_SIZE*numTracks, Tracks.GAP_SIZE*numTracks);
    }

    public void setSoundName(int numTrack, String name) {
        _track[numTrack].setText(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do it is the line _track = new SoundNameBox[numTracks]; When I debug the program this is the line that gives me problems.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to `add` the `SoundNameBox` object to the `JPanel` after instantiation.

Put this in the constructor's for loop

```
this.add(_track[i]);
```

Good luck

Comment: Glad to know it helped.